# Mac OS: Как изменить язык уже введенного текста в поисковике?

Tags: google-chrome, macos, mac

К примеру хотели мы найти `Seven Wonders of Ancient World`, но после начала ввода осознаем что ввели `Атсшуте Цщкд...` видел что опытные пользователи комбинацие клавиш меняют язык уже введенного текста.

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно этого добиться на Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

Можете установить [Punto Switcher](https://yandex.ru/soft/punto/mac/) от Яндекс.